# XmlReader doesn't read default attributes

Tags: c#

I'm reading some XML with XmlReader using the following code:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchemaSet);

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(formatXml), settings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And for each element, I read all the attributes like this:

```
while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
{
    ...
}
```

However, this code does not pick up attributes that have default values specified in the XSD schema like this:

```
<xs:attribute name="new" type="xs:string" default="error" />
```

It only picks up those attributes that are explicitly set in the XML. How do I get it to automatically get the default values from the XSD as well?

Comment: Check this out it explains why the attributes are not part of the DTD Schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302158.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out everything was working the way it should, and the default attributes were read. However there were some validation errors that I had overlooked, which resulted in the attributes not being set.

So the answer would be: Make sure your XML validate before default attributes work.